# BGE Move Toggle Switch Sensor

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

How can I create a "Toggle Switch Sensor", so when I press <kbd>W</kbd> to move a cube continuously on the Y axis, and <kbd>S</kbd> to stop the movement?
Can I do it from logic bricks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that Very simply using a Boolean property and pressing <kbd>W</kbd> to start it moving continuously and pressing <kbd>W</kbd> again to stop. See logic setup below
[image: W to start and stop]
Or you can have <kbd>W</kbd> make it start and <kbd>S</kbd> make it stop by using the setup below 
[image: more complicated logic setup]

Working blend file with Boolean property
[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to do this using a *Boolean* property and changing it using the toggle option, but it is easier to simply assign an integer a value. A Property Sensor set to pulse mode (to continually check to see if the value is still equal) and that activates your motion.

[image: logic bricks]

Blend file with working logic setup

[image]

![enter image description here][3]